# How to display image into mail using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have save image in Image datatype into database now I want to display that image into mail by using asp.net with c# how can I do this? I have used Handler, but it not working

I have search on this link but not get output
code-project link also how to display image without handler

Comment: "Not Working" will not help. Post some code you have tried and be specific where you're stuck.

Comment: Basically mail contains the html it means you need to only put the image control in html with image url of your server side image.